# Is it possible to save texts from input value on html and write on local txt file by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java

Is it possible to save texts from input value on html and write on local txt file by using JavaScript?

Also I want to know if there is best way to do what I want to achieve by using other backend language.

Answer (score 1):

Full explanation with working example here: https://robkendal.co.uk/blog/2020-04-17-saving-text-to-client-side-file-using-vanilla-js

HTML

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter some config details</legend>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <button id="btnSave">save config</button>
</fieldset>
```

JS

```
const downloadToFile = (content, filename, contentType) => {
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      const file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
      
      a.href= URL.createObjectURL(file);
      a.download = filename;
      a.click();
    
        URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
    };
    
    document.querySelector('#btnSave').addEventListener('click', () => {
      const textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');
      
      downloadToFile(textArea.value, 'my-new-file.txt', 'text/plain');
    });
```